# How to develop a reverse slicer in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

Please I need your help.

I am doing a report in PowerBi in live connection.
The model is in an azure analysis service and I am devolopping report with PowerBi. 
I need to prevent the user from selecting the same value in both slicers

In my report I have 2 slicers that are duplicated ( I am using them like a role playing dimension)
[image]

I want that when I Select "A" in the 1rst slicer I will have in the 2nd slicer the values except "A".

[image]

The goal is to prevent the user from selecting the same value in both slicers

What I want is like a reverse slicer.
Do you know how I could do it ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are these slicers based on the same data source (table/column)?

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot for your answers. These are different datasource. The 2nd table is a calculated table from the 1rst table is SSAS.